# Using X-frame for a php application to restrick clickjacking and hide directory listings

Tags: javascript, php

I want to setup x-frame or frame killer for my php codeigniter application and also restrict directory listings. There was a qualsy scan on my url and that was captured. I am using wampserver

i have tried to set header in httpd.conf for my apache but the initial test of opening the page in a frame is still failing because the page still opens in the frame, the page is only available on the corporate lan

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>  
Header always set X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block"
Header set X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff"  
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=0, public, no-cache, private, no-store"
Header edit Set-Cookie ^(.*)$ $1;HttpOnly;Secure  
Header add X-Content-Security-Policy "default-src 'self'"
Header set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=631138519; includeSubDomains"
Header set X-Frame-Options "deny"
Header always set Referrer-Policy "no-referrer-when-downgrade"
Header add Feature-Policy "vibrate *; usermedia *; sync-xhr *"

<FilesMatch "\.(js|css|xml|gz)$">  
   Header append Vary Accept-Encoding  
</FilesMatch>  
</IfModule>
```

Comment: code <IfModule mod_headers.c>  
   Header always set X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block"
   Header set X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff"  
   Header set Cache-Control "max-age=0, public, no-cache, private, no-store"
   Header edit Set-Cookie ^(.*)$ $1;HttpOnly;Secure  
   Header add X-Content-Security-Policy "default-src 'self'"
   Header set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=631138519; includeSubDomains"
   Header set X-Frame-Options "deny"
   Header always set Referrer-Policy "no-referrer-when-downgrade"

Comment: Please don't post code in the comments, hard to read. Also, how is this related to `PHP` or `javascript`? This seems to be about Apache/httpd.conf

Comment: it is a php application and that is why i have stated it that way and also i ahve used a javascript to remove any frame on the web page,